# Akka.Net ClusterClientReceptionist multinode crash

Tags: .net, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I'm trying to create a sample that create a cluster able to process an order and a client that send order.

To do so i use the ClusterClientReceptionist and ClusterClient to communicate between an client and a cluster network.

Cluster Node code :

```
namespace ClusterNode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool isFirst = false;
            using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, "5D14E338-616C-4637-93E7-E59D152DC005", out isFirst))
            {
                using (var system = ActorSystem.Create(nameof(Order), CreateConfig(isFirst)))
                {
                    var receptionistConfig = ClusterClientReceptionist.DefaultConfig();
                    system.Settings.InjectTopLevelFallback(receptionistConfig);

                    ClusterRouterPoolSettings settings = new ClusterRouterPoolSettings(int.MaxValue, 1, true);
                    ClusterRouterPool pool = new ClusterRouterPool(new Akka.Routing.RoundRobinPool(1), settings);

                    var aref = system.ActorOf(pool.Props(Props.Create<OrderProcessor>()), nameof(OrderProcessor));

                    var receptionist = ClusterClientReceptionist.Get(system);
                    receptionist.RegisterService(aref);

                    system.WhenTerminated.Wait();
                }
            }
        }

        private static Config CreateConfig(bool isFirst)
        {
            var configString = "akka { actor.provider = \"Akka.Cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider, Akka.Cluster\"\n";

            var port = (isFirst) ? 8082 : 0;

            configString += "remote { helios.tcp { hostname = localhost, port = " + port + " } }\n";
            configString += "cluster {\n seed-nodes = [\"akka.tcp://" + nameof(Order) + "@localhost:8082\"] \n";
            configString += "}\n";
            configString += "}";
            var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(configString);
            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

Client side code :

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var system = ActorSystem.Create(nameof(Client), CreateConfig()))
            {
                system.Settings.InjectTopLevelFallback(ClusterClientReceptionist.DefaultConfig());
                var client = system.ActorOf(ClusterClient.Props(ClusterClientSettings.Create(system)));

                bool quit = false;
                while (!quit)
                {
                    var str = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (string.Equals(str, "QUIT", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        quit = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    Order order = new Order() { Msg = str };

                    var respTask = client.Ask<Response>(new ClusterClient.Send("/user/OrderProcessor", order));
                    respTask.Wait();

                    Console.WriteLine(respTask.Result.ResponseMsg);
                }
                system.Terminate();
                system.WhenTerminated.Wait();
            }
        }

        private static Config CreateConfig()
        {
            var configString = "akka { actor.provider = \"Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote\"\n";
            configString += "remote { helios.tcp { hostname = localhost, port = 0 } }\n";
            configString += "cluster {\n seed-nodes = [\"akka.tcp://" + nameof(Order) + "@localhost:8082\"], ";
            configString += " client { initial-contacts : [ \"akka.tcp://" + nameof(Order) + "@localhost:8082/system/receptionist\" ] }";
            configString += " }\n";
            configString += "}";
            var config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString(configString);
            return config;
        }
    }
}
```

When i create One cluster Node and one client the sample work.
If i try to create multiple cluster node, their connect each other then directly dissasociate and the cluster collapsed.

if i comment the two folling lines the cluster work but the mechanism Receptionist/Client doesn't work.

```
var receptionist = ClusterClientReceptionist.Get(system);
receptionist.RegisterService(aref);
```

Is their a configuration missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same issue today and managed to fix it by changing to Wire serialization instead of the default Json.

I had to add Akka.Serialization.Wire from NuGet and update the serialization bindings in the config, you can see this being used in the [Cluster Tools Example](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/tree/v1.3/src/examples/Cluster/ClusterTools)

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way it work with Akka.Serialization.Hyperion also.